# Which field is suitable for image. varchar or blob. sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

Which field is suitable for the image. varchar or blob and why?

I'm using the following code to convert the image:

```
 public String getStringFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
        return Base64.encodeToString(stream.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromString(String imageString) {
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, 
                decodedString.length); 
        return decodedByte;
    }
```

my field is varchar. Is This The Way is better? Or do I have to change my way

Comment: ask uncle google for: android bitmap sqlite and you will find out the best solution

Comment: `varchar` is for character data, `blob` is for binary data (blob = binary large object). Since an image is binary data ...

Comment: when tried to save images in db I faced with error caused 2M limit of window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither one is good.

Image data tends to take a lot of space and the Android sqlite wrapper (`CursorWindow` specifically) doesn't work very well when a lot of data is being pulled from the database.

Instead, store the binary data in the filesystem and just store a path in the database.

Answer (score 0):

there is no varchar(exactly) in SQLite!!!([SQLite DataType](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html))

> NULL. The value is a NULL value.
>
> INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8
>   bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.
>
> REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE
>   floating point number.
>
> TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding
>   (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).
>
> BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

seem blob is better than other for image

Comment: SQLite does not enforce datatypes, it is only hinting and maybe casting if it knows how.

http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q3

Comment: @ikkuh yes, i know, sqlite convert the common dataType name for maximize compatibility between SQLite and other database engines, and i say in my answer there is no varchar("exactly")....